# Gerund or infinitive? "Thank you for letting me know" or "Thank you to let me know"

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

I'm finishing a letter to a friend by asking the tracking number of a parcel he sent to me. Can I finish my letter with

> Thank you for letting me know the tracking number

OR

> Thank you to let me know the tracking number

Answer (score 1):

If you want to request [something], you would probably not use "Thank you" at the start of the sentence. It is possible to make a request and start a sentence in this way, but it might be construed as a little rude because you are essentially giving a command but hiding it in the form of gratitude.

The other option that Ronald Sole proposes in his comment is valid, but I think it is a little formal (even haughty), especially for a letter between friends.

You'd be better off saying something like:

> ... and if you would send me the tracking info when you get the chance, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I might add that I believe that IE (Indian English) commonly uses "thank you" as a request in this way.  I will also add that this has been known to cause a lot of offense when Indian companies exchange emails with American or British companies.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for letting me know the tracking number.

Thank you to let me know the tracking number.

The first sentence is grammatical; you thank somebody for something/doing something. You don't use a to-infinitive with "thank" if you want to say that you are grateful to somebody for something.